# I'm trying to release a contrib module, but only see the dev version

Tags: version-control, community-official-site

I created an 8.x version of a contrib module I own (https://www.drupal.org/project/node_usage). It has a branch (`8.x-1.x`) and tag (`8.x-1.0`) and added the release, but the only 8.x one I see is `8.x-1.x-dev`. If I click "add new release", it says no valid branches or tags found, but my branch and tag look like the examples they give. What do I have to do to make a non-dev release?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just cloned the repo but there is not an 8.x-1.0 tag. You have to push the tag with `git push origin 8.x-1.0`. Then you can create the 8.x-1.0 release.

Comment: thanks - got it now